# Show $\log(\det(A))\le \operatorname{tr}(A)-n$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, solution-verification, determinant, trace

Suppose that $A$ is a real, symmetric, positive definite $n\times n$ matrix.  Show that
$$\log(\det(A))\le \operatorname{tr}(A)-n \quad \text{and} \quad \log(\det(I_n+A))\le \operatorname{tr}(A).$$

Since $A=CDC^{-1}$ we can say the following:
$$\det(A)=\det(C)\det(D)\det(C^{-1})=\det(D)=\Pi \lambda_i$$

But I'm not sure how to proceed from there. I need to somehow show that the trace is greater than the eigenvalues multiplied.

Comment: you should state what $X$ is and what $A$ is and how they relate.  As currently written the post cannot be true in any meaningful sense

Comment: We also know that $Tr(A) = \sum \lambda_i$. But what's up with $x$? What is it?

Comment: my B I meant to say A Jesus Christ my typo

Comment: You need that the eigenvalues are positive real.  This doesn't hold for the $2\times 2$ matrix $A=-I$, where $\log(\det(-I))=\log(1)=0$ but $\tr(-I)-n=-2-2=-4$.  This means there is some condition that you omitted from your problem.  You need to be careful to state ALL conditions when asking a question or you could very well ask something false (as was the case here).

Comment: @Aaron Can I edit it like this: Let $A$ be a $n\times n$ real matrix whose eigenvalues all have positive real parts.
Prove that $\log \det A \le \mathrm{tr}(A) - n$?

Comment: @RiverLi It isn't enough to have positive real parts.  For example, if the eigenvalues are $a+bi$ and $a-bi$ with $a>0$, we would get $\log(a^2+b^2)\leq 2a-2$, but the right hand side doesn't depend on $b$, and if we take the limit of the left hand side as $b$ goes to infinity, the left hand side also goes to infinity.

Comment: @Aaron You are right. Thanks.

Comment: @Aaron I saw your current edit. Do you mean $A$ is real symmetric positive definite?

Comment: @RiverLi yes. I feel free to fix the error.

Answer (score 6):

[We have](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_(linear_algebra)#Eigenvalue_relationships):

$$\mathrm{Tr}(A) = \sum \lambda_i $$

$$\det(A) = \prod \lambda_i $$

So, if eigenvalues are positive reals, we have to show

$$ \sum \ln \lambda_i \leq \sum \lambda_i -n $$

which is true as $$\ln x \leq x -1 $$
for all $x>0$